# What is "struct EVENT_LIST" on win32?

Tags: c, winapi, header-files

I am looking through the source code for [a project that relays Windows Event Log data to a syslog installation](http://code.google.com/p/eventlog-to-syslog/), in order to try to consolidate things on a network that I manage.  The program that does this needs adjustment for our application, which I am perfectly willing to do, so I dropped in the GNU build system and am currently just trying to get the thing to build under GCC.  (I do development on a Linux box.)

In any event, I cannot find this "struct EVENT_LIST" (referenced in main.h and a handful of other places in the referenced project's code, but never defined) even on a Windows system, so I cannot figure out what the data type is.  Does anyone here have any idea?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/eventlog-to-syslog/source/browse/trunk/4.0/check.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a Windows thing, it's defined [in that project](http://code.google.com/p/eventlog-to-syslog/source/browse/trunk/4.0/check.h)...

```
/* Ignored Events Structure */
struct EVENT_LIST {
        char source[50];
        BOOL wild;
        int id;
};
```

Comment: Yep, apparently I managed to overlook the "right under my nose" option.

Comment: Thanks, will accept the answer as soon as the site lets me. *headdesk*

Comment: As an aside, it seems that it wasn't directly #include'd there becuase there were no inclusion wrapper guards.  Adding both fixed my problem with it building (at least there).  I am guessing that Microsoft's compiler considers the construct they used to be valid, while GCC requires things be more explicit.